# How to create iOS- & OSX- library from Haxe and use it in native application?

Tags: ios, macos, native, haxe, hxcpp

I have an crossplatform implementation of own protocol, data-structures and logic written on Haxe. How I can build and use it in my enterprise-application (with native UI) for iOS and OSX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## How to create iOS- / OSX- library from Haxe and use it in native application

> Actuality: 12.2014; HXCPP-ver.: `3.1.39`~`git`.
>
> Dependency: `hxcpp`

### 1. Haxe -> Library

Create a new Haxe-project with main class named `HxModule`.

*src/HxModule.hx*

```haxe
class HxModule
{
    public static function main()
    {
        Sys.println('Hello from HxModule: "${test()}"');
    }

    @:headerCode
    public static function test():Int
    {
        return 101;
    }
}
```

*build.hxml*

```hxml
-main HxModule
-cp src

-lib hxcpp

# this is for Mac OS X:
-D HXCPP_M64

# this is required on Windows. the "d" stands for debug:
#-D ABI=-MTd
--each

# at this phase we create a binary for tests
-cpp out/cpp/module


--next
# at this phase we create a binary for tests
-cpp out/cpp/module

-D static_link
-D actuate
```

Build: `$ haxe buid.hxml`

### 2. Xcode-project <- Library

1. Create a new Xcode-project. It can be for OSX or iOS, Application or Cocoa Framework.
2. In the 'Project' / 'Build Setting' / 'Header Search Paths' add paths to dependencies: (all paths must be **full/not-relative** and **recursive**)

   1. `out/cpp/module/include` - you have to *fix it to full path*;
   2. `{your-haxelib-repo}/hxcpp/{version}/include` - {here-yours};
   3. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include`
3. In the 'Project' / 'Build Settings' / 'Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language - C++' change values:

   - 'C++ Language Dialect' = `GNU++11 [-std=gnu++11]`
   - 'C++ Standard Library' = `libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)`
4. In the 'Project' / 'Build Phases' / 'Link Binary With Libraries':

   - `HxModule.a`
5. Rename file: `AppDelegate.m` -> `AppDelegate.mm`
6. Edit `AppDelegate.mm`:

*AppDelegate.mm*

```objc
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "HxModule.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"test: %d", ((int)HxModule_obj::test()));
}
@end
```

Additionally for autocomplete and better navigation you can add into Xcode-project the *reference groups* from directories:

- `include` from output of Haxe;
- `include` from haxelib `hxcpp`.

Possible problems:

At the time when this text was written only one possible issue. It can be solved by editing the file `{haxelib:hxcpp}/include/hxcpp.h`. Simply add a few lines at the beginning of the file:

*{haxelib:hxcpp}/include/hxcpp.h*

```cpp
#ifndef HXCPP_H
#define HXCPP_H

// Standard headers ....

// Custom override by @suhinini
#define Class HxcppClass

// Basic mapping from haxe -> c++

typedef int Int;
typedef bool Bool;


// Windows hack
#define NOMINMAX


#ifdef _MSC_VER
   #include <typeinfo.h>
   namespace hx { typedef ::type_info type_info; }
...
```

*see after `// Standard headers ....`.*

[Example project](https://github.com/fzzr-/hx.NativeModule).

Comment: I have this setup working until I use the new operator to create an internal haxe object. e.g. 
```@:headerCode
    public static function testSimple() {
        var simple = new Simple();
}```

Comment: @TomLarkworthy, this solution work fine (but with dirty hacks in hxcpp) only before Haxe 3.2 RC.1. Very soon I'll try to update this note.

Comment: I managed to get objects created within the Haxe env with   
```
  HX_TOP_OF_STACK 
  hx::Boot();
  __boot_all();
```
before calling into the Haxe library

Comment: I have this setup working for MAC but its not working for iphone build. For ios i am encountering the issue of reference. "ld: warning: ignoring file HaxeToObjC/libTestJSiOS.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): HaxeToObjC/libTestJSiOS.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  TestJSiOS_obj::test()", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)